# jQuery Calendar Application

Tags: jquery, calendar

I need some help with jQuery Calendar application. The specific calendar I'm looking for can be found at the following addresses.. I will be glad if anyone knows and would be kind to provide me the name of the calendar that was used in the links below.

[Calendar Example 1](http://www.macroeconomics.lv/)

[Calendar Example 2](http://www.macroeconomics.lv/calendar)

Comment: you might want to look at jquery ui datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your links it's a custom-made server-side calendar. It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

On chrome right click on the page , select inspect element then go to the resources panel and check the scripts folder.